# Need help implementing WebSocket in java

Tags: java, html, websocket

I'm working on an Web Application in which multiple users work on the same data (source is sql database)

I'm using

- Netbeans 8.0.2
- Tomcat 8.0.28
- Maven 4.0.0
- jquery-2.1.4

I want the server to push a message to all clients which have opened a WebSocket Connection to my server.

I found a lot of guides/tutorials on how to implement WebSockets but they all rely on the Client pushing something to the Server.

I just need the server to push a message to the Client.

Can any1 provide a short example on how to to this??
It just needs to be:

- Client opens SocketConnection
- JavaClass establishes connection
- JavaClass method sends message/data to client

**EDIT:**

My setup right now:

On application startup I do the following:

startup.java
    package com.mycompany.ssp;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;

public class Startup implements javax.servlet.ServletContextListener {
    private static WebSocketServer socket_server = null;

    // create singleton object Socket
    getSocket();

    public static WebSocketServer getSocket(){
        if(socket_server == null) {
            socket_server = new WebSocketServer();
        }
        return socket_server;
    }
}
```

WebSocketServer.java

```
package com.mycompany.ssp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/socket")
public class WebSocketServer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(WebSocketServer.class.getName());
    private List<Session> session_list = new ArrayList<Session>();
    WebSocketServer socket_server = Startup.getSocket();

    public WebSocketServer() {
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "New connection with client: {0}", 
                session.getId());
        socket_server.session_list.add(session);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public String onMessage(String message, Session session) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "New message from Client [{0}]: {1}", 
                new Object[] {session.getId(), message});
        return "Server received [" + message + "]";
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Close connection for client: {0}", 
                session.getId());
        socket_server.session_list.remove(session);
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable exception, Session session) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Error for client: {0}", session.getId());
    }

    public void send(String message) throws IOException{
        for(Session session: socket_server.session_list){
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
        }
    }
}
```

I get an Error when trying to start my application.
Why does it happen?

Well, the Method `getSocket()` loops multiple times and everytime after

`socket_server = new WebSocketServer();` the variable `socket_server` is still null, which should be initialized though.

Netbeans Apache TomcatEE Log:

```
SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1050] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.mycompany.ssp.Startup
 java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Does any1 have an idea why this is happening??

Comment: If it was a desktop application then the way you approach the problem was true, but in web applications you do not have listeners on client side actually, so what you have to do is creating a javascript which makes an async call to the server if there is a new message. If you approach the problem in this manner it will be more easy.

Comment: Do you misunderstanding something? In WebSocket, you need to send the connection request from client to server(aka. handshaking). If the server push a message to the client without client's request. That is an "ATTACK".

Comment: I have my users viewing the same data & when data is changed by one of my java classes I want all clients to see that change right away. And iut would be best to not check like every 5 seconds if data has changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `var websocket=new websocket(websocket_url);`
2. Java Code

```
    @ServerEndpoint(value = "/websocket/one")
    public class WebsocketEndPoint {
        public static List clients=new ArrayList();

        @OnOpen
        public void OnOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig config)
                throws IOException {
            //Save the endpoints session that opened the connection in List
        }

        @OnMessage
        public void OnMessage(Session session, String message) {


        }

        @OnClose
        public void OnClose(Session session, CloseReason reason) {
         //remove from list
        }

        @OnError
        public void OnError(Session session, Throwable throwable) {



            }
        }
    }
```

3.

```
class Sender{
    public void send(String message){
            for(Session session:WebsocketEndPoint.clients){
                session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps

And in Javascript u can use onMessage to get the message